# Ubuntu Software app not loading

Tags: 16.04, lts

Opens for a few seconds without any data and closes again.
Shows empty squares with 3 dots in cetre of each.

Comment: Please start it from console and write the result in here

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: solved.entered "software-center" in terminal and reloaded

Answer (score 0):

I thought typing install software-center packaging

`sudo apt install software-center`

### would work.

I typed : software-center
and it worked. not sure if this is the best method, I'm a new linux user

Comment: This is not an answer, if you have a question, ask here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Please write a more detailed answer - the method is good because it is general (can be used in all versions and flavours of Ubuntu.